# What happens in Eclipse CDT on Linux if you press the Terminate button?

Tags: linux, signals, eclipse-cdt

I guess some signals will be sent to the process. Some or one? If more than one in which order do they occure?

And what happens if the Terminate button is pressed and if the process has forked?
And what happens if the process has started other processes by system(...)?

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure without checking, but I would be surprised if the signal sent was anything other than SIGTERM (or possibly SIGKILL, but that would be a bit unfriendly of CDT).

As for sub-processes, depends what they are actually doing. If they are communicating with their parent processes over a pipe (in any way whatsoever, including reading their stdout), they'll likely find that those file descriptors close or enter the exception state; if they try to use the fds anyway they'll be sent a SIGPIPE. There may also be a SIGHUP in there.

If a sub-process was really completely disjoint (close all open FDs, no SIGTERM handler in the parent which might tell it to exit) then it could theoretically keep running. This is how daemon processes are spawned.

Answer (score 0):

I checked SIGTERM, SIGHUP, SIGPIPE with terminate button. Doesn't work...
I guess it is SIGKILL and this makes me very sad! Also, I didn't find a good solution to run program from external(or built-in plugin) console.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be SIGKILL. SIGSTOP is used by GDB to stop/resume. From `signal` man page:

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught or ignored.

I tried to debug following program with eclipse. Pressing `terminate` in Run session or `pause` in Debug session does not print anything. Thus it must be either `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler(int sig) {
    printf("\nsig:%2d %s\n", sig, strsignal(sig));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int signum;
    int delay;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: continue <sleep>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    delay = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (signum = 1; signum < 64; signum++) {
        signal(signum, handler);
    }

    printf("sleeping %d s\n", delay);
    for(;;) {
        sleep(delay);
    }

    return 0;
}
```